# Why is momentum as time constant is different in the first epoch with parallel training?

Tags: cntk

Given configuration `momentumPerMB=0.9`, I observe the value of `momentumAsTimeConstant` in the first epoch way off. Remaining epochs have this value as expected. This seems to happen only in parallel training (1bit and BM, didn’t verify for MA yet).

`01/11/2017 00:08:08: Starting Epoch 1: learning rate per sample = 0.000500  effective momentum = 0.900000  momentum as time constant = 155504.2 samples`
`01/11/2017 00:18:04: Starting Epoch 2: learning rate per sample = 0.000500  effective momentum = 0.900000  momentum as time constant = 19438.0 samples`

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

We recommend specifying `momentumAsTimeConstant` because this measure is invariant to mini batch size.

Comment: Can you say a bit more here? How do I see from the logs that something goes wrong? What are the signals I should watch out for? When is it better to use one vs the other?

Comment: Monitoring the loss function trajectory over epochs s a good was to monitoring how your training is going.